# How to force a marker drag in Google Maps JavaScript API (V3)?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When adding a marker to a google v3 map, I want to automatically begin dragging it. The click event that adds the marker is already on the canvas, and so I want the same click event that adds the marker to also act as a drag start. Very similar to how it's done when adding markers to a Google MyMaps map (though I'm pretty sure that still uses V2).

Is this possible, or do I have to add the marker, then make it follow the mouse around until the user clicks again, then drop?

Answer (score 2):

Add
"draggable: true," to the marker's options.

Example:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  draggable: true,
  position: somepoint,
}); 
marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if adding draggable: true to the marker is what your looking fOr or if it is beyond that?  Hope this helps

Comment: Marker is draggable. It just takes 2 clicks. 1 to add marker, second to start dragging it. Want to immediately drag on first click.